# I would like to count of each unique letter in a string by using c#.net

Tags: c#

I would like to write a problem to read a text file from command line and to output the count of each unique letter, sorted alphabetically. Any suggestions for this program in C#
Example :

Stack overflows

Output :

a 1
c 1
k 1
t 1
s 2

Comment: Its pretty easy but I think you should do your own homework, thats what your course intends. If you cant do that then please drop out.

Comment: Your example and the example output don't seem quite right to me...

Comment: I will vote anyone down that actually provides this cheater with a working solution. Jon Skeet posts (and along that line) are helpful though if the OP actually will absorb some advice is another thing.

Comment: Kiran, we don't mind helping people with their homework here, but we expect you to have tried to work out a solution on your own. Then, post the code that you have, and we'll help you from there.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, it sounds like homework. I'll just give you some hints:

- Split the task up. There's no need for the "processing" code to depend on the input coming from a file, or the output going to the screen.
- If you're allowed to, look at LINQ which provides sorting, grouping and counting functionality in a very easy-to-use way.
- For bonus points, implement unit tests for the processing part...

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ, one way to get the unique characters is:

```
string s = "Stack Overflows";

var x = from c in s.ToLower()
        group c by c into a
        select new { a.Key, Count = a.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string s = "stack overflows";
        Dictionary<char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        foreach (char x in s)
        {

            if (dic.ContainsKey(x) == true) 
            {

                dic[x] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dic.Add(x, 1);

            }

        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> x in dic)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(x.Key + " " + x.Value);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

class Test
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputstring = "stackOverflows";
        charcount(inputstring, inputstring.ToCharArray()[0]);
    }

    public static void charcount(string recstring ,char c )
    {
        if (recstring.Length != 0)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (char c1 in recstring)
            { if (c1==c)
            {

                count++;
            }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(c+"  "+count);
            string tempstring = recstring.Replace(char.ToString(c), "");
            if (tempstring.Length != 0)
            {
                charcount(tempstring, tempstring.ToCharArray()[0]);
            }
        }

    }
```